# Why is this generic method signature invalid?

Tags: java, generics

```
static void stuff(Thing thing, Iterable<T extends Something> stuff){
    ...
}
```

This doesn't compile, Eclipse puts a red line under `extends`. However if I change `T` to `?`, it works. Why?

Answer (score 4):

Try :

```
static <T  extends Something> void stuff(Thing thing, Iterable<T> stuff){
    //... 
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `static <T extends Something> void stuff(Thing thing, Iterable<T> stuff)` ?